# Reiniciar contagem ao mudar o ano

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Possuo uma View que me retorna dados que o contribuinte pagou a previdência no ano atual, onde retorno o pagamento mensal do mesmo. Necessito realizar a soma dos meses, criando um subTotal mensal. Com ajuda eu consegui funcionar, deixando o resultado como o exemplo:
[Exemplo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/wnh933xg/1/)

Porém necessito que a soma reinicie ao virar o ano. Esta lógica que não estou conseguindo elaborar.
Preciso que o resultado final torne algo do tipo:
[Exemplo Resultado esperado](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/9qj04130/)

Meu controller está assim:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
           //realizo a busca no BD
            var usuario =
                previdenciaRepository.Previdencias.Where(p => p.CdMatricula == matricula && p.SqContrato == contrato).ToList();       

            return View(usuario);
        }
```

E na view que faço o calculo para somar os dados retornados, ficando assim:

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">
                    Mês
                </th>
                <th colspan="4">
                    <p align="center">
                        Contribuinte
                    </p>
                </th>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <th>
                    %
                </th>

                <th>
                    R$ Ano
                </th>
                <th>
                    Acumulado R$
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Previdencia.GroupBy(g => g.NmPessoa))
            {
                double subtotal = 0;
                foreach (var contribuicoes in item.ToList())
                {
                    subtotal += contribuicoes.Contribuinte;
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => contribuicoes.dtCompetencia)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            11
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => contribuicoes.Contribuinte)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @subtotal.ToString("c")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Meu Model está assim:

```
public class Previdencia
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 Cod_Previdencia { get; set; }
        public int CdMatricula { get; set; }
        public Int16 SqContrato { get; set; }

        public string NmPessoa { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? dtCompetencia { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastante simples. Basta mudar o seu `GroupBy()`.

Por comentário foi perguntado sobre a totalização sobre todos os registros. Isto pode ser feito inicializando uma variável fora do loop e incrementando ela dentro do loop:

```
        @{ var total = 0; }

        @foreach (var item in Model.Previdencia.GroupBy(g => new { g.NmPessoa, g.dtcompetencia.Year }))
        {
            double subtotal = 0;
            foreach (var contribuicoes in item.ToList())
            {
                subtotal += contribuicoes.Contribuinte;
                total += contribuicoes.Contribuinte;

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => contribuicoes.dtCompetencia)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => contribuicoes.dtcompetencia)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => contribuicoes.Contribuinte)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @subtotal.ToString("c")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
```

Comment: Como sempre, me ajudou de novo.
Só uma dúvida. Para conter os dois campos, como deveria proceder? O total e contando por ano? Assim: http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/9qj04130/1/

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Pode ser pelo mês também. Ou pode ser por um agrupamento montado por você. A criatividade é o limite.

Comment: Eu entendi essa parte. Porém necessito salvar a soma total (sem zerar por ano) em outro campo (como foi feito com a variável **subTotal**). Teria como fazer isso criando outra variável? Ou prefere que abra outra pergunta?

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Não precisa. Já coloquei na resposta. Veja se te atende.

Comment: Muito obrigado mais uma vez, era exatamente isso. As vezes eu mesmo fico perplexo com a facilidade de meus problemas. Mas é assim mesmo. rsrs